# Passing NSString to Webview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have an `NSString` called status and I am trying to pass that variable to load a `webView`. The app is crashing here, but I don't know what I am doing wrong? Does anyone see anything wrong with the request?

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?status=%@", status]]];
```

Comment: The app is just crashing, and Im pretty terrible at reading crash logs.

Comment: Can you edit the question and include the error message you get? Try logging the value of `status` just before the call as well.

Comment: Run the app in debugger. If it crashes, Xcode will show an error in the console. Post the complete error. The debugger will also show which line of code is causing the problem. Post that code.

Comment: Thanks all - You guys were right - passed as an NSString instead of an NSURL. Converted as advised

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`requestWithURL` accepts `NSURL`, So you need to convert string into `NSURL`

Try this,

```
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?status=%@", status]]]];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?status=%@", status];
//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 3):

`+[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:]` is expecting you to give it an `NSURL` object.  You're giving it an `NSString`.  Don't do that. :)

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. I wonder why the compiler didn't warn him.

Comment: @JackLawrence Too many people think it's OK to ignore warnings. For every project I setup, the first thing I do is turn on the "Treat warnings as errors" compiler setting.

Comment: @rmaddy I've been tempted but I've never taken the plunge.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?status=%@", status]]]];
```

Comment: NSURL URLWithString: this new

Comment: @Ayaz I believe the point being made is that you are simply repeating the other answers well after the others appeared. There is no reason for you answer. It provides nothing new that hasn't already been stated. Why bother? And your posted code isn't valid anyway. It won't compile.